# SOQL query to query from child to parent and then to another child

Tags: soql

I am checking if it is possible to construct a SOQL query using the below object structure.

I am using the out of the box WorkOrder object to query Account fields from the Account object.

I have a Custom_Object__c which has a lookup relationship to the Account object. I want to know if it is possible to query the Custom_Object__c fields keeping the FROM WorkOrder clause.

Here is the query I constructed so far -

```
SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber, WorkOrder.Account.Name FROM WorkOrder
```

Now how do I include the fields of the Custom_Object__c onto the above query keeping the FROM WorkOrder clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Custom_Object__c which has a lookup relationship to the Account

It means, that `Custom_Object__c` is a child of `Account` object. That means, that there may be many children for a particular `Account` record.

Making, an assumption, that the parent field on `Custom_Object__c` to `Account` object is `Account__c` and the child relationship name is `Custom_Objects__r`

First, you can try parent-to-child relationship queries

```
SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Account.Custom_Objects__r) FROM WorkOrder
```

but it returns an error

> First SObject of a nested query must be a child of its outer query.

so it is not possible to `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account.Custom_Objects__r`

It can't be achieved as limitation exists because SOQL does not support joins in the same way that SQL does; it only allows traversal through direct parent-child or child-parent relationships.

---

However, you can change the approach of your SOQL query to start from the `Account` object instead of `WorkOrder`. This allows you to access fields from both `WorkOrder` and `Custom_Object__c`

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Name,
    (SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber FROM WorkOrders),
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Custom_Objects__r)
FROM 
    Account
WHERE
    ...
```

---

Or if this is allowed for you, can be done in 2 SOQL queries

1. ```
   SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber, Account.Name, AccountId FROM WorkOrder
   ```
2. collect `AccountId` to `accountIds`
3. ```
   SELECT Id, Name, Account__c FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds
   ```

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr for the detailed explanation.